# Wordpress Query posts that have title > another title

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to make a query of a custom post type that searches the next 3 posts alphabetical order after a specific title. A snippet of the args wp_query is

```
$vars = array(
    'paged' => $page, 
    'posts_per_page' => intval($posts), 
    'order' => 'asc', 
    'offset' => ($offset ? $offset : ''), 
    'orderby' => 'title' 
);
```

but have no clue how to query posts where title > specific title.

Comment: And what is your question and where is your code. Please visit [ask] and [help] and learn what a good question should look like, then come back and file an [edit] with your code and a proper explanation of your problem, and remember, *doesn't work* is **not** a failure/problem description. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_page_by_title` to match the title of the required post.

```
$post_name = get_page_by_title( 'Post Title' );

$vars = array(
   'name' => $post_name,
   'paged' => $page, 
   'posts_per_page' => intval($posts), 
   'order' => 'asc', 
   'offset' => ($offset ? $offset : ''), 
   'orderby' => 'title' 
 );
```

Comment: This is returning me one post, i need the next 3 posts after this one in alphabetic order.